# Gtk button-press-event on a Label

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

Is it possible to use the signal `button-press-event` on a GtkLabel? I tried to register a signal and nothing happened, so what can I do to make it work?

Comment: If you send your (hypothetical) little brother to the bakery to buy a pocket calculator... What do you expect to get? Registering a signal handler for a certain widget is useless if the resp. widget doesn't emit this signal. I wonder that this is even possible. I assume you somehow abused casts or the generic API of GTK+ (which is implemented in C). APIs of other widget sets (implemented in C++) prevent such things more reliably from the beginning. FYI: [GTK+ 3: Label - Signals](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html#GtkLabel.signals)

Comment: @ritsi: others can better help you if you describe your question in such a way that it's clear what you're trying to achieve, rather than trying to shoehorn some approach you were trying to figure out. Depending on your use case, there are multiple other/better solutions :-)

Comment: @Scheff the inspector (when I press ctrl-shif-i) says that button-press-event *is* connected on the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an Event box is what you need, if not, then you really need to provide a code for this.

Here is a Demo:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean button_press_event_clbk ( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event )
{
    g_return_val_if_fail ( GTK_IS_LABEL ( widget ), FALSE );

    switch ( event->type )
    {
        case GDK_BUTTON_PRESS :
            printf ( "The Button was Pressed\n" );
            return TRUE;

        case GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE :
            printf ( "\tThe Button was Released\n" );
            return TRUE;

        default:
            return FALSE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

int main ( void )
{
    /// ***
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *label;
    GtkWidget *event_box;

    /// ***
    gtk_init ( NULL, NULL );

    /// *** create a new window
    window = gtk_window_new ( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL );
    gtk_window_set_default_size ( GTK_WINDOW ( window ), 200, 200 );
    g_signal_connect ( window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK ( gtk_main_quit ), NULL );

    /// ***
    event_box = gtk_event_box_new();
    gtk_container_add ( GTK_CONTAINER ( window ), event_box );

    /// *** Create the label
    label = gtk_label_new ( "Click here" );
    gtk_container_add ( GTK_CONTAINER ( event_box ), label );

    /// ***
    g_signal_connect_swapped ( event_box, "button-press-event",   G_CALLBACK ( button_press_event_clbk ), label );
    g_signal_connect_swapped ( event_box, "button-release-event", G_CALLBACK ( button_press_event_clbk ), label );

    /// ***
    gtk_widget_show_all ( window );

    /// ***
    gtk_main ();
}
```

Output:

```
The Button was Pressed
    The Button was Released
```

Comment: [Take a look Here](https://www.youtube.com/c/MichaelB-GTK/playlists) If you need to learn more about GTK